# Stomp protocol in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I don’t feel comfortable using WebSocket with Codename One and Spring Boot. Maybe my “error” was the implementation of one my own communication protocol over websocket, featuring ack and other hard to implements things. My protocol have issues that I wasn’t able to fix... I spent a lot of time creating it, but there are too much complexities for me.

Today I discovered that I tried to reinvent the wheel... since there are protocols over websocket like STUMP:

https://www.toptal.com/java/stomp-spring-boot-websocket

STOMP is a simple text-based messaging protocol that was initially created for scripting languages such as Ruby, Python, and Perl to connect to enterprise message brokers. Thanks to STOMP, clients and brokers developed in different languages can send and receive messages to and from each other. The WebSocket protocol is sometimes called TCP for Web. Analogically, STOMP is called HTTP for Web. It defines a handful of frame types that are mapped onto WebSockets frames, e.g., CONNECT, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE, ACK, or SEND. On one hand, these commands are very handy to manage communication while, on the other, they allow us to implement solutions with more sophisticated features like message acknowledgment.

Is there any Stomp implementation for Codename One? Or the implementation of any other protocol over websocket? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not at this time. I also tried looking for implementations in Java but couldn't find any. It would actually be really nice if we had something like that.

I found an [implementation for Android](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid) but I didn't get the chance to look at the complexity of porting it to Codename One.